# android studioでrunしようとするとエラーが多数出ます。

Tags: android, android-studio

以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されます。

```
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\Janken\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:26: AAPT: error: '100' is incompatible with attribute layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\Janken\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:26: AAPT: error: '100' is incompatible with attribute layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　エラーの解決は、一般的にはエラーメッセージだけから判断するのは難しいです。どのように作ったアプリなのか書いてみたり、具体的なソースコードを書いてみたりなど、どうやったら回答者がこのエラーを再現できそうかの情報を、質問文を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 表示された助言
”Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.”
[直訳]
「試してみる事：
　Run　に　--stacktrace　オプションを付けて実行すると、スタックトレース（エラー発生に至るまでのプログラムの実行履歴）が得られます。」
に従って、まずはスタックトレースを見てみるのが良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージは、"'100' is incompatible with attribute layout_width (attr) dimension"
[直訳] '100'は、layout_width の属性に合っていません。
というものです。

androidの要素の幅や高さの指定には、"dp"という単位を使いますから、'100'を'100dp'に修正するとエラーは解消すると思われます。

他の、「incompatible ｘｘｘ attribute ｘｘｘｘｘｘ (attr) dimension」というようなエラーがでた箇所も同様に、数字の末尾に"dp"を追加する事で解消できるかと思われますので、修正してみてください。

補足：
dpは、(Density-independent pixel)の意味だそうです。